# How to move box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

[image: Hint]

This is CSS how it's described

```
.hint {
 background: url('/triangle.png') center right no-repeat;
 padding-right: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

How to move a shadow 10px left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all with CSS (no need for an image):

```
.hint {
    background:#F85B58; 
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.hint:before, .hint:after {
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:100%;
    width:0px; 
    height:0px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:-10px;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-left-color:#F85B58;
}
.hint:before {
    margin-top:-8px;
    border-left-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ro9nfhw6/

Change the `border-width` to make the arrow more acute (as per your example):

```
.hint:before, .hint:after {
    border-width:6px 10px;
}
```

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/ro9nfhw6/1/

Comment: Do bare in mind, support for :before and :after in older browsers isn't great, if it exists at all.

Comment: @evilunix Noted, but support is pretty decent - [all the way back to IE8 in fact](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .hint-outer {
    background: url('/triangle.png') center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 10px;
 }

 .hint-inner {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    height: 100px;
 }


 <div class="hint-outer"><div class="hint-inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: The problem is though, that you need to split your markup into multiple divs, and apply shadows to them seperately. Box shadows will always apply to the entire div, even if parts of it appear to be transparent to you.

Comment: It moves a shadow but the shadow appears on the left side

Comment: Is the problem the shadow in the bottom right? You need to split your code into an outer and an inner DIV and only apply the drop shadow to the inner div.

Comment: You would need two elements each with their own box-shadow and the triangle 'element' would need to be transformed.